# How to find posts that are missing translation? (wpml)

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

I have a page with hundreds of posts that should all be available in two languages. In the admin area however I have differing post counts – so I guess some of the posts are not translated. Instead of scrolling the post list in both languages and comparing the lists basically post by post I would love to do the searching programmatically. Maybe there is even a plugin I don't know of? I suppose this is possible – I just can't get the right starting point.

Would appreciate any pointers or suggestions on this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern: finally I found a way – and it turns out to be rather simple: there is a wpml function or actually a filter that checks whether a post or page has a translation or not:

`wpml_element_has_translations`

https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_element_has_translations/

It returns TRUE if a translation exists and FALSE if there is no translation. I used the following to check for posts inside the loop where $the_id is the ID of the post I want to check:

`$is_translated = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_has_translations', NULL, $the_id, 'post' );`